# TFS 2015 and shared steps

Tags: mtm, tfs

I wanted to know if there is any way to create a shared step form TFS 2015 without using MTM, and if there is please let me know how, thanks!

Comment: Did you try using Web interface of your TFS instance?

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft, the TFS 2015 web interface supports [Shared Steps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/mtm/share-steps-between-test-cases?view=azure-devops).

You should note that Microsoft has deprecated MTM and will not be releasing any new versions. That makes migrating to the web interface something you should be considering anyway.